# Unable to redirect to a dynamic URL in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js

In my Next.js 14 app, I have a `/research/page.tsx` file where I am receiving a file as user input and sending it to a server-side API for further processing. Here’s the method that does this:

```typescript
const handleFileDrop = async (file: File) => {
    // Convert file to blob
    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
    const paperId = await generateFileId(arrayBuffer)
    const paperTitle = file.name

    // Send file to api/upload for upload to S3
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: file,
      })
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error(await res.text())
      console.log(await res.json())
    } catch (error: any) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
```

On the server, the API at **/api/upload/route.ts** is meant to do a bunch of things with the file and once done, redirect the user to a new dynamically generated route:

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import generateFileId from "@/lib/generate-file-id"
import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf"
// import AWS from "aws-sdk"

// const s3 = new AWS.S3()

async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream) {
  return new Uint8Array(await new Response(stream).arrayBuffer())
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const data = await request.body
  if (!data) return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
  const arrayBuffer = await streamToArrayBuffer(data)
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
  const loader = new PDFLoader(blob)
  const pageLevelDocs = await loader.load()
  const pageCount = pageLevelDocs.length
  const paperId = await generateFileId(arrayBuffer)

  /*
  STEP 1: Upload file to S3
  STEP 2: Add reference to file in Postgres
  */
  console.log("test")
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/research/${paperId}`, request.url))
}
```

Everything works fine down to the `console.log("test")` statement. But the redirect wouldn’t work. The browser stays on `/research` instead of redirecting to `/research/[paperId]`.

I even tried redirecting from the client upon a successful response from the API, using `useRouter` and `router.push()` but even that wouldn’t work:

```typescript
const handleFileDrop = async (file: File) => {
    // Convert file to blob
    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
    const paperId = await generateFileId(arrayBuffer)
    const paperTitle = file.name

    // Send file to api/upload for upload to S3
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: file,
      })
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error(await res.text())
      console.log(await res.json())
      const router = useRouter()
      router.push("/research/${paperId}")
    } catch (error: any) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
```

The browser remains on the originating URL.

I have two questions:

What is missing in my code, and
What is the conventional approach to this situation? I need the new page to be able to access the `file` object too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect a network call made via JavaScript like you did. Instead, you would return a normal response:

```typescript
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const data = await request.body;
  if (!data) return NextResponse.json({ success: false });
  const arrayBuffer = await streamToArrayBuffer(data);
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
  const loader = new PDFLoader(blob);
  const pageLevelDocs = await loader.load();
  const pageCount = pageLevelDocs.length;
  const paperId = await generateFileId(arrayBuffer);

  /*
  STEP 1: Upload file to S3
  STEP 2: Add reference to file in Postgres
  */
  console.log("test");
  return NextResponse.json({
    success: true,
    paperId: paperId,
  });
}
```

And handle the redirection on the client:

```typescript
// In the component body:
const router = useRouter();

const handleFileDrop = async (file: File) => {
  // Convert file to blob
  const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
  const paperId = await generateFileId(arrayBuffer);
  const paperTitle = file.name;

  // Send file to api/upload for upload to S3
  try {
    const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: file,
    });
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error(await res.text());
    const { paperId } = await res.json();

    router.push(`/research/${paperId}`);
  } catch (error: any) {
    // handle error
  }
};
```

At this point, if you have a `research/[paperId]/page.tsx`, you are good to go.